# Filtering email address registration form with custom domain

Tags: php, html, wordpress

hope you're doing great! i'm wondering if you can help me with my codes? i was decoding my word press theme and i want to have a filter email registration. here is my code

```
this.register_new_validator = $("form#signup_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    first_name: "required",
                    last_name: "required",
                    user_login: "required",
                    user_pass: "required",
                    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $email)) return false;

        $domains = array('ac.uk');
        list(, $email_domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
        return !in_array($email_domain, $domains);
    },
                    repeat_pass: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#user_pass"
                    }
                },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    var required_id = $(element).attr('id');
                    var $container = $(element).closest('div');
                    if (!$container.hasClass('error')) {
                        $container.addClass('error').removeClass(validClass);
                    }
                },
            });
```

I tried this also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.validator.addMethod('nofreeemail')
            {
                if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $email)) return false;

                $domains = array('ac.uk');
                list(, $email_domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
                return !in_array($email_domain, $domains);
            }

        });

        this.register_new_validator = $("form#signup_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    first_name: "required",
                    last_name: "required",
                    user_login: "required",
                    user_pass: "required",
                    user_email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        nofreeemail: true
                    },
                    repeat_pass: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#user_pass"
                    }
                },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    var required_id = $(element).attr('id');
                    var $container = $(element).closest('div');
                    if (!$container.hasClass('error')) {
                        $container.addClass('error').removeClass(validClass);
                    }
                },
            });
```

When i hit the submit button the page is just reloading. thanks!

Comment: If it's showing errors, please include those errors.

Comment: What are the errors if you can post them would be easier for the community.

Comment: the errors is that if you tried registering to the form, when you hit submit, its just redirects to the page. it doesn't do anything. so maybe there's wrong with my code.